# Disable IE8 Popup Blocker CLI No Registry

Tags: powershell, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, popup-blocker

Is there a way to disable IE8s popup blocker application using command line of some sort? Preferably Powershell? I don't want to use any commands to touch the registry. For all intents and purposes imagine I only have local user access with no administrative privileges, and I only want to effect the local users profile. This is being used to do an initial profile setup for a users new PCs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Or change the website code that relies on this bad behavior.

Comment: Hahaha if that were a choice I would go for it, but that isn't soooooo yeah I'm working on changing the IE settings instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The popup blocker is configured in Registry. It can be set up via group policy, registry editing and clicking through IE menus. There are [no relevant startup parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documented. Registry settings are divided to computer and user contexts; the former doesn't need special permissions. A [group policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/843016) doesn't require special permissions from the user.

The last resort is to use a tool like Autoit to simulate clicking through IE menus. It is the most error prone a way, and I'd avoid it as far as possible.